# MVC layout not being found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC 3 application that has a default view and a second view, which I will refer to as SecondView.  SecondView has a corresponding controller, SecondViewController.

SecondViewController.cs contains two procedures: `Index()` and `LoadSecondView(id)`, both return `View("SecondView")`.

SecondView.cshtml consists of:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SecondView";
    Layout = "~/Views/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Second View</h2>
```

If my main index.cshtml calls window.open("SecondView"), then the page loads as expected, using the layout that is in Views/_MasterLayout.cshtml.

However, if it calls window.open("SecondView/LoadSecondView/id-parameter-string"), then _MasterLayout thinks the "current directory" is /SecondView/LoadSecondView rather than /, and all of the links to (e.g.) images now point to the wrong place, so the entire layout is ignored.  (The same thing happens if LoadSecondView does not take any parameters, and the call URL is just "SecondView/LoadSecondView".)

Is there a way to call a procedure (other than "index") in a controller that would then load a view that would look in the correct place for layout?

Comment: So your question is not actually about the MVC layout not being found, but your resource paths being incorrect?

Comment: Well, when you put it that way...and actually, when you put it that way, I think I solved the problem - when I put a "/" in front of each URL in the layout file, it seems to work now.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a tool like [Glimpse](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx) to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your issue is about Relative and Absolute Paths..

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

You use relative paths, which means relative to the current directory.

Use `/path` to force the path to start resolving from the root. That is called an absolute path in the sense that regardless of where you start it always points to the same location..